# Adding caption to fancybox images/video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I currently have `fancybox` displaying all the correct images/videos that it should. However, I cannot seem to get it to display the caption associated with each time `fancybox` is called.

I am using **Fancybox V2.1.5**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".fancyYoutube").live('click',function(){
$.fancybox({
'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
'titleShow' : 'true',
'speedIn' : '100',
'width' : 680,
'height' : 395,
'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
'type' : 'swf',
'swf' : {
'wmode' : 'transparent',
'allowfullscreen' : true,
},
beforeLoad: function() {
this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
}
});
return false;
});
});
```

I am using `caption=` within the sections it is required, however it still doesn't display the caption text :(

I am also using the latest JQuery plugin with it.

Any help would be great, thanks!

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".fancyYoutube").live('click',function(){
$.fancybox({
'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
'title' : this.title,
'speedIn' : '100',
'width' : 680,
'height' : 395,
'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
'type' : 'swf',
'swf' : {
'wmode' : 'transparent',
'allowfullscreen' : true
}
});
return false;
});
});
```

Only needed `title : this.title,`

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well(I checked here too: http://fancybox.net/blog ) you need these parameters

```
'titlePosition'         : 'inside',
'titleFormat'       : formatTitle
```

Where the formatTitle is a function which appends the caption

```
function formatTitle(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
    return '<div id="tip7-title"><span><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.fancybox.close();"><img src="/data/closelabel.gif" /></a></span>' + (title && title.length ? '<b>' + title + '</b>' : '' ) + 'Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' of ' + currentArray.length + '</div>';
}
```

I think there is something wrong here

```
this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
```

Try using ids with something like this(wherever it does not fit use an appropriate id)

```
$(this).html( $(this).attr('caption') );
```

Comment: Am i correct that `caption=` will need changing to `title=`?
Also, i had found that blog section too, however it didn't even allow fancybox to load. http://pastebin.com/ND0GNXYk is correct is it not?

Comment: Actually I don't think there is any problem with whatever you use since the .attr('caption') takes whatever you tell it to. 

Check my edit

Comment: Have now altered my code to include `beforeLoad: function() {
$(this).html($(this).attr('caption') );
}` instead of `this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');` and fancybox doesn't load at all now and just links to the image/video

Comment: It was an indication. 

Try putting an id to the span you want to have the caption. Let's say id="cap"

$('#cap').html( $('#<id of the element>').attr('caption') );

Comment: Also, remove the function from the fancybox code lines!!! It needs to be an external function

Comment: I THINK I have it correct now, however you note that #<id of the element> however ALL the fancybox sections use a class so that they share they same properties. 
http://pastebin.com/Ze7tbyXm might give you a better idea of how my code is structured